# Post list based on the user that is logged in

Tags: users, user-access

I've been all over this site and google, and the WP codex looking for an answer to this one. I know it's out there, and I know it's easy. Maybe has something to do with user_nicename, but I just can't make it work.

What I'm trying to do for the site I'm working on is eliminate any need and any ability for the user to see the backend of the blog. This means front-page everything: Login, Post, and if I can swing it - a dash board.

I envision changing the "site admin" link on the wp login/logout code to link to a blog page called "User Dashboard" there, the user could view a list of their posts and comments.

Really reaching for the stars, they should also be able to see a list of comments on their posts, and really really reaching for the stars - some kind of messaging system.

I'm currently simply trying to get the post list down! I can't figure out how to return the_author post list based on a dynamic setting of where the request is coming from. IE: Only list the current logged in users posts/comments. There is a plugin called Full Author User List or something to that affect, that doesn't work anymore as it's outdated.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there you go, i'm not the only one trying to bring back-end functionality to the front-end.
anyway its not that hard go to your "USER DASHBOARD" template's file and locate where the loop starts something like:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

and just above it paste this code:

```
<?php
/* First get the user info */
get_currentuserinfo();
/* Then query_posts by user id */
query_posts(array('author'=>$current_user->ID));
/* And Last just loop thrugh the posts */
?>
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: You're a rockstar and my hero!!

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately this isn't working? It's the same list for every user. Maybe I am running through the loop incorrectly, I just used the general one from codex, could you maybe give me a full example? Thanks either way!  :s

Comment: Oop. I got it. Just an idiot. and tired.

Comment: :), happy you got it.

Comment: Hello, I am also interested in the solution to this problem. Where can I locate USER DASHBOARD template to be able to put the code?
Thanks.

Comment: You have to create the template yourself.